# Calling method leading to loss of array data (arguments passed)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So I am currently working on a project for class and I am at the end but I am running obviously into a javascript error. We are told to use Polyglot markup and html 5 standards.

Issue: I am calling a method and passing it 4 things (array race[0], array name1, array party1, array votes1). Once my code reaches the method according to the debugger I am losing the entire first array therefore shifting all the array data.

Here is my call for showResults function

```
showResults.call(race[0], name1, party1, votes1);
```

and here is the function showResults

```
   function showResults(race, name, party, votes)
   {
        var totalV = totalVotes(votes);
        var result = "";

        result += "<h2>" + race + "</h2>";
        result += "<table cellspacing = '0'>";
        result += "<tr>";
        result += "<th>Candidate</th>"
        result += "<th class='num'>Votes</th>";
        result += "<th class='num'>%</th>";
        result += "</tr>";

        var percent = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) 
        {
            result += "<tr>";
            result += "<td>" + name[i] + '(' + party[i] + ')' + "</td>";
            result += "<td class='num'>(" + percent[i] + "%)</td>";
            result += createBar(party[i], percent);
            result += "</tr>";
        } 

        result += "</table>";

        document.body.innerHTML = result;
   }
```

according to the debugger I believe I am either calling the function incorrectly, at least that's all I can think of.

Here is a part of the javascript file so you can get an idea

```
var race = ["", "", "", ""];

var name1  = [ "", "", ""];
var name2  = [ "", "", "", ""];
var name3  = [ "", ""];
var name4  = [ "", "", ""];
var name5  = [ "", "", ""];

var party1  = [ "", "", ""];
var party2  = [ "", "", "", ""];
var party3  = [ "", ""];
var party4  = [ "", "", ""];
var party5  = [ "", "", ""];

var votes1  = [ "", "", ""];
var votes2  = [ "", "", "", ""];
var votes3  = [ "", ""];
var votes4  = [ "", "", ""];
var votes5  = [ "", "", ""];


race[0]="1st Congressional District";
race[1]="2nd Congressional District";
race[2]="3rd Congressional District";
race[3]="4th Congressional District";
race[4]="5th Congressional District";

name1[0]="Sarah Carlson";
party1[0]="D";
votes1[0]=45125;
name1[1]="Pete deJesus";
party1[1]="R";
votes1[1]=44498;
name1[2]="Alan Tompkins";
party1[2]="I";
votes1[2]=5143;
```

I assigned empty "" to each array because CSE validator was throwing errors and the teacher will deduct points for each error.

Any help would be appreciated and super interested to see why this is actually happening.

Comment: why do you use call? just invoke the function as every other function func(), so remove the .call and do ```showResults(race[0], name1, party1, votes1);```

Comment: I figured it was something minor I was overlooking, this worked I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

`The call() method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually.`

Looks like you need to pass `this`.

`function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
}`

`Product.call(this, name, price);`

Comment: the answer has nothing to do with the question, neither is op using this inside his function neither is he utilizing the Product class

Comment: `showResults.call` is being used without `this` as an argument and therefore the function showResults believes `race[0]` is where `this` should be. I could spell it out but a bit of common sense would help to work this out.